# Is there anything important in /var?

Tags: security

Is there anything important in /var/ such that if something gets corrupted/deleted, it would break the system?

Comment: What kind of system and what services are you running?  Sometimes things like apache use directories under `/var` for the default location for content, and `postgresql` and `mysql` do the same.  Also, break it how?  Break it such that a reboot will recover or break it so that the running system is crippled?

Answer (score 4):

`/var` is generally where program data gets stored (web content, logs, mail and print spools, etc.). If you lose `/var` your system will *probably* still boot but any service that maintains state across reboots will *probably* lose that state.  Without knowing exactly what distro you're running and what services are installed and running it's hard to answer your question with any more certainty.